Postfix problem
I am using Kubuntu 24.04 LTS. When I try to upgrade software using
apt full-upgrade I get:
oyo@oyo-Z270-HD3:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Paket listeleri okunuyor... Bitti
Bağımlılık ağacı oluşturuluyor... Bitti
Durum bilgisi okunuyor... Bitti               
Yükseltme hesaplanıyor... Bitti
Aşağıdaki paket otomatik olarak kurulmuş ve artık bu pakete gerek duyulmuyor:
  libcdb1
Bu paketi kaldırmak için 'sudo apt autoremove' komutunu kullanın.
0 paket yükseltilecek, 0 yeni paket kurulacak, 0 paket kaldırılacak ve 0 paket yükseltilmeyecek.
1 paket tam olarak kurulmayacak ya da kaldırılmayacak.
Bu işlem tamamlandıktan sonra 0 B ek disk alanı kullanılacak.
Devam etmek istiyor musunuz? [Y/n] y
Ayarlanıyor: postfix (3.8.6-1build2) ...

Postfix (main.cf) configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, 
edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix 
configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'systemctl reload postfix'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 1.1.1.1
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter mydomain: bad parameter value: 1.1.1.1
dpkg: postfix paketi işlenirken sorun yaşandı (--configure):
 postfix paketi post-installation betiği kuruldu alt süreci 75 hatalı çıkış kodu ile sona erdi
İşleme sırasında hatalarla karşılaşıldı:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Sorry for some reason my computer starter to reply ir Turkish.
What is going on? How can I solve this problem?

You should be able to get messages in English by setting the LANGUAGE environment variable e.g. sudo LANGUAGE=C.UTF-8 apt full-upgrade . FWIW your situation seems to be the same as Error during "Running newaliases"
